# Road network comparisons - how to extract roads that do not completely fall within the buffer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, road, comparison

I am trying to compare how well one road network aligns with another - I have created a buffer around the first network and would like to select only the roads from the second network that fall COMPLETELY within that buffer, OR only have small extensions that go beyond.

I have done both a clip and erase of the second network by the buffer and joined those sets to find the set that fall both within and outside the buffer to remove them, but need to find a way to not remove those that "mostly match"

i.e. how can I remove the roads that do not match the buffer but are included because part of the road is within the buffer, as in a T intersection, without also removing those roads that have smaller parts not falling within the buffer?

It doesn't have to be a 100% solution, there is room for a reasonable amount of error

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Multipart To Singlepart (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003r000000) it will break up the roads into single parts, which should make your selection more accurate.

Comment: The road sections are already individual features